# how can i run this script automatically on azure for DTU

Tags: sql, azure, powershell, azure-sql-database

```
 $ServiceObjective = Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServiceObjective -ServerName exampledb-ServiceObjectiveName S0
 Set-AzureSqlDatabase -DatabaseName exampledb-ServerName exampledb-ServiceObjective $ServiceObjective
```

I can run above script to make my sql database S0 DTU level,

Can i make this automatically.

BTW i searched on forums and stackoverflow,
 they recommend automation account and runebook.
But i dont have RunAsAccount. I dont have admin privileges and i cant create RunAsAccount. So i couldnt use runbook.

can you recommend me another way ?

Thanks :)

Comment: you can have a look at azure function with powershell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell. it is a good alternative to runbook = cheaper. you can run a script x minutes to check whatever you need.

Comment: is it fora non production envrionment ? For development you may want to use `Azure SQL Database serverless`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-serverless. it will scale up and down based on load and inactivity. I am using it for dev workload and it is great.

Comment: Last thing would be to create alert metrics:https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/sql-database/sql-database-insights-alerts-portal. then you use a webhook to point to your azure powershell function.

Comment: thank you a lot. why don't you write these as answer :)

Comment: So did you really try to create the automation account? AFAIK, to use that, no need to be the admin.

Comment: @Joy wang, how can i use it ? can you show me other way?

Comment: You just need to ask the `Owner` in your subscription to create an automation account with run as account for you, then you will be able to create a powershell runbook and run your command above with e.g. `Contributor` role. Because when creating the run as account(service princiapl), it will automatically add it in your subscription, but if you are not an `Owner`, you will not be able to do that. If you just want to use the runbook, no need to be the `Owner`.

Comment: @lewisatep sorry too lazy this week to write proper answer ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But i dont have RunAsAccount. I dont have admin privileges and i cant create RunAsAccount. So i couldnt use runbook.

If you want to create an Automation account with run as account, you need to have `Owner` role in your subscription, because when creating the run as account(service principal), it will automatically add the service principal in your subscription as a `Contributor`, it just can be done with `Owner`.

But if you just want to use the runbook in automation account, you don't need the `Owner` role. You just need to ask the `Owner` in your subscription to create an automation account with run as account for you, then you will be able to create a powershell runbook and run your command above with e.g. `Contributor` role.

After the `Owner` creating the automation account for you, follow the steps below.

1.Navigate to the automation account -> `Runbooks` -> Create a runbook -> create a Powershell runbook.

2.The two commands `Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServiceObjective`, `Set-AzureSqlDatabase`, you are using belong to `Azure` i.e. ASM powershell module, it is old, and if you want to use them, you need to use Azure Classic Run As Account(which is not supported in CSP subscription). So I recommend you to use the new `Az` powershell module.  In your automation account -> `Modules`, check if there are `Az.Accounts` and `Az.Sql` module, if not, in the `Modules` -> `Browse Gallery`, search for the modules and import them.)

After importing successfully, use the script as below to login and set the sql db with Standard S0.

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Connect-AzAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

Set-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "<resource-group-name>" -DatabaseName "<database-name>" -ServerName "<server-name>" -Edition "Standard" -RequestedServiceObjectiveName "S0"
```

3.If you want to run the script automatically with a schedule, you can follow this link [**Scheduling a runbook in Azure Automation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/schedules) to do that.